# Source Code Relation between class-based views and its Models

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

According to [Django official URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#generic-views-of-objects),

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
    class Publisher(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
        state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        ...
```

`views.py`

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from books.models import Publisher

class PublisherList(ListView):
    model = Publisher
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from books.views import PublisherList

urlpatterns = [
    path('publishers/', PublisherList.as_view()),
]
```

In the template, a variable called `object_list` that contains all the publisher objects.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Publishers</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for publisher in object_list %}
            <li>{{ publisher.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

I have been deep diving into source code of django to find out exactly where Django explicitly put all objects of the `Publisher` model into the template context (`object_list`). But no luck so far, Can anyone share some insights please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView` is a child class of `BaseListView`. The `object_list` attribute is initialised [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ca9872905559026af82000e46cde6f7dedc897b6/django/views/generic/list.py#L142):

```
class BaseListView(MultipleObjectMixin, View):
    """A base view for displaying a list of objects."""
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()  # <--
        ...
```

and the default implementation of the `.get_queryset()` method is [defined in `MultipleObjectMixin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ca9872905559026af82000e46cde6f7dedc897b6/django/views/generic/list.py#L21):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Return the list of items for this view.
    The return value must be an iterable and may be an instance of
    `QuerySet` in which case `QuerySet` specific behavior will be enabled.
    """
    ...
```